# Add PGP key as attachment in Evolution

Tags: evolution, pgp

Using Evolution 3.28.1-2 (installed from the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories) and added my PGP key to one of my accounts. It works fine but Evolution inlines my PGP key instead of adding it as an attachment.

This works of course but confuses my colleagues since all mails start with the cryptic `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----` text.

Is there a way to tell Evolution to add the public key as an attachment instead? I though that was how it worked in the Evolution version I used in Ubuntu 17.10 but I might be mistaken.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, think I found it. There is a "Prefer inline sign/encrypt for plain text message" option in the "Security" tab of the account settings, not sure how I missed that.

Case closed.